# Pandas date formatting with different multiple date formats problems

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column in my dataframe to dates, which are meant to be birthdays. The data was manually captured over a period of years with different formats. I cant get Pandas to format the whole column correctly.

formats include:

```
YYYYMMDD
DDMMYYYY
DD/MM/YYYY
DD-MMM-YYYY (eg JAN)
```

I have tried

`dates['BIRTH-DATE(MAIN)'] = pd.to_datetime(dates['BIRTH-DATE(MAIN)'])`

but i get the error

> ValueError: year 19670314 is out of range

Not sure how I can get it to include multiple date formats?

Comment: Should a value like 19670304 be interpreted as 3rd April or 4th March?

Comment: 19670304 should be March

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own function to handle this. For example, something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '20180101', 1: '01022018', 2: '01/02/2018', 3: '01-JAN-2018'}})

def fix_date(series, patterns=['%Y%m%d', '%d%m%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', '%d-%b-%Y']):
    datetimes = []
    for pat in patterns:
        datetimes.append(pd.to_datetime(series, format=pat, errors='coerce'))
    return pd.concat(datetimes, axis=1).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]

df['fixed_dates'] = fix_date(df['date'])
```

[out]

```
print(df)    

          date fixed_dates
0     20180101  2018-01-01
1     01022018  2018-02-01
2   01/02/2018  2018-02-01
3  01-JAN-2018  2018-01-01
```

Comment: what is the 's' in pd.to_datetime(s, format=pat, errors='coerce') ?

Comment: @ThelurkerLurker apologies, it should indeed be `series` and not `s`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

In my eyes `pandas` is really good in converting dates but it is nearly impossible to guess always the right format automatically. Use `pd.to_datetime` with the option `errors='coerce'` and check the dates which were not converted by hand.